# Unable to use moment.js inside Greasemonkey script

Tags: javascript, momentjs, greasemonkey

Pasting the snippet of my Greasmonkey script below -

Header of my greasmonkey script

```
// @version     1.0
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js
// @require     http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.2/moment.min.js
// @require     http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.9/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js
// @grant       GM_xmlhttpRequest
// @grant       GM_addStyle
```

Call to the moment -

```
console.log(details3.responseText);
serviceLocalTimeZone=details3.responseText;
console.log(moment.tz.zone(serviceLocalTimeZone));
var momentTimeZone = moment().tz(serviceLocalTimeZone);
console.log(momentTimeZone);
```

Here is how the output of the above looks like in the console, for the above statements.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3u]

Clearly it shows that its not loading in the file - moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js

It would be great if someone could help here.

Comment: You need to edit your question to provide an [MCVE].  The snippets shown have multiple omissions and will not run as is, so we can't replicate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

According the documentation at https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/, to use the time zone data you've loaded, you must explicitly call the `add` function to add it to `moment`. Try adding a call to `moment.tz.add('Europe/London');` or a more granular dataset, as specified in their examples.

Comment: But, I am also including the js in the @require - http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.9/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js , which has all the timezones, so that should add them itself.

Comment: Try removing the `moment` include (line 2) - I think `moment-timezone` includes `moment` so it could be a redifinition somewhere.